# onClick event is not getting triggered in React horizontal scrolling menu library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am using ScrollMenu from React horizontal scrolling menu i wanted scroll on mouse drag so i added it like this

```
 <ScrollMenu
        LeftArrow={LeftArrow}
        RightArrow={RightArrow}
        onWheel={onWheel}
        onMouseDown={() => dragStart}
        onMouseUp={() => dragStop}
        onMouseMove={handleDrag}
      >
        {items.map(({ id }) => (
          <Card
            title={id}
            itemId={id} // NOTE: itemId is required for track items
            key={id}
            onClick={handleItemClick(id)}
            selected={id === selected}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollMenu>
```

i have a cta inside card that is redirectng me to another page in react.above you will see onMouseUp event if i add dragStop in onMouseEvent the onClik event does not even triggre. even an alert inside it or console log inside it is not getting triggred

```html
const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);
  const [dragging, setDragging] = React.useState(false);
  const position = React.useRef(0);

  const dragStart = React.useCallback((ev: React.MouseEvent) => {
    position.current = ev.clientX;
    setClicked(true);
  }, []);

  const dragStop = React.useCallback(
    () =>
      // NOTE: need some delay so item under cursor won't be clicked
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setDragging(false);
        setClicked(false);
      }),
    []
  );

  const dragMove = (ev: React.MouseEvent, cb: (posDif: number) => void) => {
    const newDiff = position.current - ev.clientX;

    const movedEnough = Math.abs(newDiff) > 5;

    if (clicked && movedEnough) {
      setDragging(true);
    }

    if (dragging && movedEnough) {
      position.current = ev.clientX;
      cb(newDiff);
    }
  };

  return {
    dragStart,
    dragStop,
    dragMove,
    dragging,
    position,
    setDragging
  };
```

you will find the whole code in there documentation drag by mouse example. there it is working when i am using it is not

Comment: while I can't be sure because you don't share the definition of `handleItemClick`, I am almost certain what you really want is `onClick={() => handleItemClick(id)}`. With what you have now `handleItemClick` will be called once for each `id` as soon as the compoment mounts - and not again when actually clicking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onClick not working React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401902/onclick-not-working-react-js)

Comment: no forget handleItemClick, i have a cta inside that card clicking on which i am redirecting to different page and when i remove onMouseUp it is working but with onmouseUp dragstop call it is not @RobinZigmond

Comment: also if the link you provided was the issue. i wouldn't reach out on stackoverflow.

Comment: apologies if that's not the issue, it's just what leapt out at me from your code, especially given the description you give of "onClick event not getting triggered"

Comment: ohh no worries , thanks for adding an answer @RobinZigmond